# In Rails, how would I show a 'Goodbye' page that is *only* accessible immediately after the user signs out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was recently using Svbtle.com where they show a page immediately after logging out. It says "Goodbye.", along with link to go "Back to SVBTL".

I like the idea of a 'farewell' page, similar to how they did it, and would like to do something similar in a project I'm working on.

The 'farewell' page on Svbtle has a path of https://svbtle.com/notify?logout. When you reload the page or try to navigate to https://svbtle.com/notify?logout, it redirects you to the site landing page.

What is this magic?

How would I go about only showing a page upon user logout, but then prevent them from visiting it otherwise?

I'm using `Rails 5.0.0.1` and Devise for authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a static goodbye page with whatever content you want. Edit your `routes.rb` and give the goodbye page a route (we'll call it `goodbye_page_path` for illustrative purposes here).

Go into `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` and create a method called `after_sign_out_path_for`, which is a standard Devise helper. Set it up like this:

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  goodbye_page_path
end
```

That should redirect users to your goodbye page whenever they log out.

To prevent access to the goodbye page, store a flag in the [session object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session). In the controller method handling logout:

```
session[:goodbye] = true
```

In the controller method that handles displaying the goodbye page:

```
def goodbye_page
  if session[:goodbye] && session[:goodbye] == true
    render 'goodbye_page'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any idea how I could restrict this path so that it is only accessible immediately after logout? I'm trying to make it so that a user can't simply visit the goodbye_page_path without the action of logging out.

Comment: Thank you, again, for your response—I'm continually grateful for the help of the Ruby/Rails community. But I gotta say, you are completely wrong that I'm asking a different question. The title states the page should _only_ be visible immediately after logout. I go on to describe the desired behavior that the 'farewell' page should not be accessible by navigating to it via url and explicitly wrote that the end goal is to show the page immediately after logout but **prevent them from visiting it otherwise.**

Answer (score 0):

I started implementing this and wanted to share what I went with. I tried writing to `session` initially but ran into problems as `session` wasn't available after logout where the GoodbyeMessagesController scope lies. I ended up going with a cookie that is set immediately after sign out, then deleted in my goodbye controller:

*ApplicationController*

```
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    cookies[:single_view_page] = true

    goodbye_path
  end
```

*GoodbyeMessagesController*

```
def show
  if cookies[:single_view_page]
    cookies.delete :single_view_page

    # Other logic...
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

It ended up being super easy, and it works great.